# How to open lightning app after login to salesforce?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I have one lightning app "home.app" and i want to open this app after salesforce login for some specific profiles only. Can you please help in this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Host `home.app` in a Lightning Out Visualforce page.

There is a lot of documentation on the web about how to do this. But for completeness, here is an actual VF page that you could use (after you change the name of the app and component):

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="lightning" />
    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:YourLightningApp", function() {
          $Lightning.createComponent("c:YourLightningComponent",{},"lightning",function(cmp) {});
        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Put this Visualforce page on a Homepage that you assign only to certain profiles.

In Classic You can assign page layouts from:

> 1. The object's customize page layout or record type page
> 2. The original or enhanced profile user interface.

In Lightning:

> 1. Lightning App Builder—From Setup, enter Lightning App Builder in the Quick Find box, then select Lightning App Builder.
>      After you save a page, click Activate from the Page Saved dialog, or click Activation and select Assign this Home page to specific profiles.
> 2. Home in Setup—From Setup, enter Home in the Quick Find box, then select Home.
>      Click Set Page Assignments or click action list dropdown next to a profile and select Change Assignment.

Classic Link [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=assigning_home_page_layouts_to_profiles.htm&type=0)
Lightning Link [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_home_lex_assign.htm&language=en_US&type=0)